# How does setContentView work in android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display a button on my android app but everytime i run the app it crashes. i realise this is because i use setContentView multiple times? I dont understand how it works, and dont understand how i can fix this problem so my button will display. my code is below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Draw draw;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        draw = new Draw(this);
        draw.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        setContentView(draw);

        LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
        l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        setContentView(l);
        l.addView(new Draw(this));
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        setUpBlockBtn();
    }

    private void setUpBlockBtn(){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button addBlockButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBlock);

        addBlockButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("DemoButtonApp", "you clicked the button");
                //finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you add your button to the layout? And what is `Draw`?

Answer (score 0):

You try to access Button from android xml layout but you do not set this layout in Activity.

Put you button activity_main.xml and use this button in your activity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create one more layout and add Draw and Linear layout to that layout.

Something like this.

```
LinearLayout l1=new LinearLayout(this);
l1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

l1.addView(draw);
l1.addView(l2)   // your linearLayout.

setContentView(l1)
```

Remember you can't use setContentView more than one time.
There should be top layout which includes subview and other layouts and then you can add that layout to your activity.